# Keras predict_on_batch and predict is quite slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using Keras (and the Keras Retina Net) to extract text from a photo and transcribe that text. The text is part of a document, I extract the ROIs from the photo into small snippets like these:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

The reason for extracting the ROIs is for accuracy. If I run the entire photo through prediction, it fails horribly to produce anything useful. The method with the ROIs works but is quite slow.

There are around 50-80 ROIs per photo and each of them takes 0.3 to 1.3 seconds, depending on how much text is on the ROI. Is there a way to speed this process up?

Hardware

- NVIDIA RTX 2080 Ti
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4440 CPU @ 3.10GHz
- 32GB DDR4 RAM

Tensorflow Version

- tensorflow-gpu 1.13.2 (installed via bazel)

Does anyone know of a different way to transcribe the letters and numbers that would work a lot faster?